# CSS: disabling select on container, enabling on child (not working in Firefox)

Tags: css, selection, css-cascade

So the following works in Chrome, but not FireFox:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input {
    -webkit-touch-callout: auto;
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    -khtml-user-select: auto;
    -moz-user-select: auto;
    -ms-user-select: auto;
    user-select: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to disable selecting on container elements, but allow things like form inputs to be selectable?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 11.0 / Lion. http://jsfiddle.net/pmcelhaney/z2BXn/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions (trying to be creative)

1.try to simply write:

```
:not(input) {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

this rule should be applied to everything except the `input`, so that there's no need of another rule that reverts the behaviour for inputs (that maybe it's failing on some FF version?)

---

2.if this doesn't solve try to cheat using `-moz-selection/selection` pseudoclasses with a transparent background on user selection

```
::-moz-selection { background: transparent; color: #000; }
::selection      { background: transparent; color: #000; } 

input::-moz-selection { background: blue; color: #fff; }
input::selection      { background: blue; color: #fff; }
```

as a sidenote for the sake of the usability avoid this kind of restrictions: they're commonly irritating and if someone want to really select and copy the text on your page, he could easily do it from the source code view

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like all versions of FF support that pseudo class. The reason I'm doing it is because in this "web app" I want to preserve some of the app-like appearance by having everything but inputs be selectable. But it's not an absolute necessity just an aesthetic preference.

Comment: `-moz-selection` is supported since Firefox 1, see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3A%3Aselection

Comment: Sorry, I meant the ":not" selector.

Comment: that's why I suggested two different approaches :)